# How to use SPLIT and CROSS APPLY functions in BigQuery

Tags: split, google-bigquery, cross-apply

I'm struggling with the split and cross apply functions in BigQuery. However it didn't work. If anyone can help that will help me a lot in my project. Thanks! I want the output looks like this:

[image: The output I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays):

```
select deptid, deptname, value
from mytable, unnest(split(deptlocation)) as value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DeptId,
  DeptName,
  SPLIT(p, ",") AS Value
FROM
  your_tbale,
  UNNEST(DeptLocation) AS p
```